# Crypting file with python

Tags: python, file, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: how to encrypt a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936543/python-how-to-encrypt-a-file)

I'm trying to make application that need write secret data in file and allow read data from this file with only user password. do you know any methods for encode/decode file with pass phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [PyCrypto module](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).

However, due to the poor documentation and no official tutorials, you may wish also to see [how to encrypt files with AES](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/).

Answer (score 1):

You never considered using Google before asking?
The official [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html) has a bunch of tutorials regarding hashing and encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The best-known cryptographic library for Python is [PyCrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org/).  To read in a password in the console, use the [`getpass` module](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) included with Python.